# Black colors in some applications backgrounds

Tags: kde, themes, colors, 19.10

I install KDE on Ubuntu GNOME and set on `sddm` and again remove full KDE and set to GTK, after do it some apps color black and problem.

I see this problem on Ubuntu store and disk application.

How to solve this problem?

[image: Ubuntu store image]

[image: disk application]

Comment: Try install gnome-tweaks and change style to Yaru. If it is already Yaru, change to something else, apply, and change back.

Comment: i do it not work @pLumo

Comment: Did you figured out?